# How to do these three things in a SQL Server transaction - 1. create table, 2.create trigger on table, 3. select from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to accomplish the following 3 simple tasks as a transaction (i.e. I need to lock old_table and new_table until the process completes).

1. Create a new table  (new_table)
2. Add a trigger to old_table, which queues updates to new_table.
3. Select all the data from old_table and return it.

Note that I want these handled in a single transaction.  I cannot allow inserts into old_table (and therefore triggered inserts into new_table) in between the trigger creation and the select on old_table.

My current closest attempt is this, but truthfully I feel that I am very far off from accomplishing my goal with this code.  I have added the code just for reference of what I am trying, but I am mostly interested in non-specific answers that layout how to accomplish the above three comands in a transaction.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.BuildAll;

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.BuildAll
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @TriggerCode VARCHAR(MAX)
   
    CREATE TABLE dbo.new_table
    (
        status nvarchar(5),
        type   char(1),
        col1   nvarchar(50),
        col2   smallint
    )

    SELECT @TriggerCode = 'CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
                           ON dbo.old_table FOR INSERT  
                           AS
                              DECLARE @col1_new nvarchar(50)
                              DECLARE @col2_new  smallint 
    
                              SELECT @col1_new = col1 FROM inserted
                              SELECT @col2_new = col2 FROM inserted
        
                              IF @col1_new IS NOT NULL
                              BEGIN
                                  INSERT INTO new_table (status, type, col1, col2)
                                  SELECt "Q", "A", @col1, @col2 FROM inserted
                              END'
       
    EXEC(@TriggerCode)
  
    SELECT * FROM old_table

    COMMIT
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: This honestly looks like a solution to a problem that's probably solved in some much better way, possibly using features you don't yet know about. If you're trying to produce some time-stable snapshot of data, consider temporal tables or snapshot isolation; if you want to switch tables atomically, look at `ALTER TABLE SWITCH` or executing `sp_rename` in a transaction; if you need to replicate data, consider transactional replication. I can't think of any scenario where the above approach with a trigger would be necessary or desirable.

Comment: This looks bizarre, perhaps it's [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Explain what you're attempting to do as an overview.

Comment: @Stu It is not an XY problem.   For the problem statement, I have edited in a hope to add clarity.

Comment: @marc_s For the trigger logic, I have noted your concern and will enhance that.

Comment: Curious why you are writing a procedure with dynamic SQL to do this, I assume this is a once off operation so you could just run the batch as is, without using dynamic. Don't forget that `CREATE TRIGGER` statements must be the only command in the batch

Comment: @Charlieface I read that in order  to do this whole thing as a transaction, I would have to put it in a stored procedure, but then to run a trigger in a stored procedure requires you run it dynamically (because who the hell knows why).

Comment: As I said, it needs to be the only statement in the batch, so that's why dynamic is necessary if you put it in a procedure. Why does it need to be in a procedure and in one transaction anyway? What could possibly happen if you create the table without the trigger? And if you need it in a transaction you could in theory just run it from your client one part at a time (separate the different parts with `GO` and SSMS will do that for you)

Comment: Still not understanding the requirement to put this is a procedure and transaction. You need to create a new table and have a trigger on an existing table insert rows into the new table. Just create the new table, then create the trigger on the old table. As soon as it's created it will fire for all new inserts, you can then if required run a one-time population for all rows in the old table that do not exist in the new table. Your trigger code is still flawed, you cannot use local variables in that manner.

Comment: @Stu, I wanted to lock the table from being inserted (and updating to the new table via trigger) while i pull the data.  Let me try and simplify this.  I need a transaction which can 1. Create a table, 2. implement a trigger, 3. pull data from the initial table.  I do not want writes/updates getting in while i do this process.  I am less concerned with getting the trigger correct than I am with understanding why TSQL will not let me put these three statements together into a transaction.

Comment: @DaleK I appologize.  I suspect I was editing at the same time you made a change.  My head has cooled a bit now, and I have simplified the question.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to suggest this an a possible solution you can try. This doesn't address the correctness of your actual trigger, you have two separate questions here really.

You don't need to encapsulate this entire process in a transaction.

- Create your new table.
- Create your trigger on old table, but disabled.
- 

```
set transaction isolation level serializable
begin tran
go
create trigger <Name> on <Table> etc
go
disable trigger <Name> on <Table>
go
commit
```

- Now in a transaction you can lock the old table against other activity while you work
- 

```
begin tran

update oldtable with(tablockx) set column=column where id=0 /* block other processes from updating table, id=0 row doesn't exist */

query your data and process as required

enable trigger <Name> on <Table>

commit
```

Comment: This  strategy well when I ran it from  dbeaver, however I still get the following error when trying  to pass the above as a string  from C#:

"CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch."

That being said, your solution works well and I think it should be marked correct, for those who come looking in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This trigger code of yours is kinda odd .... you have a trigger on all three operations - yet it appears as if you're never using the values you fetch from the `deleted` pseudo table, and if the value from the `inserted` table is `NULL`, you're not doing anything inside your trigger - so you can really spare yourself the `DELETE` case - that'll never do anything....

Also, as mentioned in my comment - you `Inserted` pseudo table can easily contain **multiple rows** - but you're selecting from it as if you only ever expect it to contain a single row.

You should **really** rewrite your trigger code to handle the case of multiple rows in `Inserted` and make the whole thing *properly set-based* - something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
ON dbo.old_table 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    INSERT INTO new_table (status, type, col1, col2)
        SELECT 'Q', 'A', i.col1, i.col2
        FROM Inserted i
```

Whether you need this on the `UPDATE` case at all - I cannot tell, you need to decide this. But basically: just select from the `Inserted` table, take the `Col1` and `Col2` values, and add the constant values `'Q'` and `'A'` to your insert to handle multiple rows properly. That should do it.

Comment: have removed the unused values per your comment, but left the I will actually be using the  logic for all three scenarios, (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), but for simplicity I now only include add in the above code.  What I'm struggling with is why I can't build a transaction that includes the creation of the trigger with the table  create and the select statement.  That is where I am having trouble.